# Difference between _variablename and variablename

Tags: solidity

```
contract Student{
    struct stu{
        string name;
        uint age;
        bool tookTest;
    }
    mapping(uint => stu) public studentNames;
    function addStudent (uint ID, string _name, uint _age) {
        studentNames[ID] = stu(_name, _age, false);
    }
    function updateStudent (uint ID) {
        studentNames[ID].tookTest = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no difference between them in solidity.

Comment: hey, suggest some materials to start creating contracts in solidity

Comment: I recommend https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.9/.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between both of that. Generally, developers use it to differentiate global variables and function arguments (variablename for global variable and _variablename for function argument).

If you want to create a smart contract then this [BitDegree Solidity Course](https://www.bitdegree.org/courses/solidity-smart-contract/) will be very helpful to you, If you are a beginner.

Then go ahead and take a look at https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/